# jQuery: do something if select element exists

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, jquery-selectors

Hey, I looked around on Stack Overflow and tried a few other people's attempts at this, and I just couldn't get this to work.

I have a select element like this:

```
<select id="slct_firstCat" name="slct_firstCat" size="15">
</select>
```

This only shows once a specfic AJAX request has completed, so this select element is NOT loaded with the original page's DOM, it is loaded as a seperate AJAX request after the main page has loaded.

I basically want to do this...

```
if (/* select element exists */) {
  // Then change the colour of a div to green
} else {
  // Change the colour to red
}
```

But remember, this has to work **after** the page has loaded. I can click the select to run the JS function if needed.

I tried this code below, but couldn't get it to work:

```
if ($(".element1").length > 0 || $(".element2").length > 0 {
  // code
}
```

So basically, if the select element exists, then change the tab colour to green, else change it to red.

Comment: Couldn't you detect the completion of the AJAX request and do your `...stuff...` in the `.success()` callback?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to put your code in `jQuery.ajax()`'s success callback. And the `> 0` part isn't needed in `$('.element1').length > 0`, since—unlike in Ruby—, `0` and `""` are also [falsy](http://11heavens.com/falsy-and-truthy-in-javascript) in JavaScript.

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: 'example.php',
    success: function () {    
        if ($('#slct_firstCat').length) {
            $('#myDiv').css('color', 'green');
        } else {
            $('#myDiv').css('color', 'red');
        }
});
```

Comment: If you don't use $myDiv var and use selector directly, it will search only once (in this case), so it isn't needed.

Comment: @EdgarVillegasAlvarado: Nope, you're wrong. It will search only once if I **do** store it in a variable.

Comment: Look at your code. `$myDiv.css(...)` only executes **ONCE** (cause it cant enter in both if and else branches) so storing it doesn't help **at all** in this case.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use something like:

```
 if ($('select#slct_firstCat').length) {
    // ... stufff....
  }
```

Comment: `input#slct_firsTcat` won't work. It's a select, not an input. And jQuery doesn't have an `.exists()` function.

Answer (score 1):

move your if block to ajax success it will work

just giving an example

```
$.ajax({
  url: "test.html",
  context: document.body,
  success: function(){
   if ($(".element1").length > 0 || $(".element2").length > 0 {
  ...stuff...
}
  }
});
```

Comment: +1 for the success callback, -1 for not showing how to color the div—so no vote from me.

Comment: @nyus, thats fine , i thought he already has code...for changing color. , i looked at your answer..thats good

Answer (score 0):

You should change the colours when your events happen, i.e. when your ajax call succeeds, starts, or when you trigger another event. Anyway, you could use this code, that isn't the best way to do it, but suits your needs:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  setInterval(function(){
      if($("#slct_firstCat").size() > 0)
          $("#divColour").css("backgroundColor", "green");
      else
          $("#divColour").css("backgroundColor", "red");
  }, 100);
});
```